# Django dynamically add field from dictionary value

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to refactor some code to be DRY

I have an importer that imports from an API that has keys that are different than the destination.

Working code looks like this:

```
this_event = AnEvent()
wp_event = Requests.get('someurl').json()
if 'title' in wp_event.keys():
    this_event.name = wp_event['title']
if 'description' in wp_event.keys():
    this_event.description = wp_event['description']
... and so on
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
scrape_fields  = [
    {
        'wp' : 'description',
        'django' : 'description'
    },
    {
        'wp' : 'title',
        'django' : 'name'
    }
    ... etc
]
for field in scrape_fields:
    if field['wp'] in wp_event.keys():
        # I knew this would not work when I wrote it but not sure what to do
        this_event[field['django']] = wp_event[field['wp']]
```

But Django throws an exception:

```
'AnEvent' object does not support item assignment
```

Is anyone able to advise on how to assign to a field dynamically like this?

Comment: Are there any duplicated `'wp'`s or `'django'`s values? If not we can boost performance of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically assign any Python object's member values using `str` type values to reference the field name you need to use Python's built-in function `setattr`. Essentially, this line:

```
this_event[field['django']] = wp_event[field['wp']]
```

Can be rewritten to this, using `setattr`:

```
setattr(this_event, field['django'], wp_event[field['wp']])
```

Read: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Answer (score 1):

You want `setattr()`:

```
setattr(this_event, field['django'], wp_event[field['wp'])
```